# Docker + Django + Better approach of passing N Environment variables during image build

Tags: docker, django-rest-framework, dockerfile

I have a project in Django and I am building the image through docker and we have 30 environment variables in the jango application, we used environ module for maintaining env variables.

And we have simple docker file where we don't have volumes and we are using python manage.py collectstatic in docker file.

When docker image is building, we are getting error at the step of calling python manage.py collectstatic and this command is expecting all the 30 environment variables otherwise docker image build is failing.

And if we pass all variables in docker file using ARG it is working fine.

My question is what is best approach to pass 30 environment variables while running this python manage.py collectstatic ?. Instead of build-args

We followed the approach by taking all settings in one pyhon file and we are pointing that file in docker as
ARG DJANGO_MODULE_SETTINGS = python_file.

But I am getting error as collectstatic unknown command and please look for python manage.py help.

Kindly advise.

Comment: You need all 30 environment variables as build args, not at runtime?

Comment: I need just at image building time.

Comment: Ah. There's no simpler way to provide multiple build args than using multiple flags — this is possibly by design, since each ARG adds a new layer, which means slightly larger and slower builds.

Comment: Oh Ok, So there is no other option other than passing as individual ARG for each variable or as build args ? instead of passing variables as ARG in docker file, we created seperate python file and we have kept all the variables in that file and we have kept ARG DJANGO_MODULE_SETTINGS = pythonfile.py and we are calling above variable just before calling python manage.py collectstatic and now we are getting error as collectstatic is unknown,

Comment: Can you give an example of what some of these are?  Since a Docker image is fairly fixed and isolated from other environments, there are a lot of things you don't really need to configure (installation path, user ID, port number, ...).

Comment: Variables like,  cache url, third party app urls,  third app Id,  secret key , bucket names and others variables are related to third party applications and if I remove the step collectstatic command docker build is successfull.

Answer (score 3):

I'm writing this answer for future users

you can use the default value when getting .env variables,
this means when your image is building and no .env file exist Django settings file running with default variables and hence no function except the collect static command is running, there's no error,

in case of using [django-environ](https://django-environ.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) module for handling env variables
you just need this syntax in your settings.py for every variable you are using:

```
SECRET_KEY = env.get_value("SECRET_KEY", default="default")
```